# Can reverse micelle's exist outside solution?

Tags: thermodynamics, solutions, enthalpy, entropy

As in reverse micelle's, the polar liquid remains inside the micelle while the exterior is one of lower dielectric constant; if the liquid were to be carefully removed, would the micelle structure remain?
I reason so as the air or medium outside the micelle would still be of a lower dielectric constant, so it is still favourable to remain with that structure. Is this sensical?

Comment: Putting the polar groups (e.g., [CTAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cetrimonium_bromide)) close together in the centre of a reverse micelle likely is more costly than letting the alkyl chains mingle in normal one exposed to polar media. In your question, do you permit the inverse micelle to be covered by a «normal» one?  This then leads to liposomes which are used as carrier for dyes (-> spectroscopy) and medication (phototherapy, carrier of mRNA/DNA vaccines, etc.) ...